Keep the soft keyboard open when switching apps on Android (Flutter)
Description
Initial situation:

A text field in my app has the focus. The soft keyboard is open.

The user temporarily switches to another app.


Expectation:

When the user switches back to my app, the soft keyboard should be ready immediately.

In fact, the soft keyboard is hidden. I first have to click on it again.
With Flutter (unfortunately):
I can monitor via WidgetsBindingObserver when my app is back in the foreground and show the keyboard again via SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show'), but the keyboard is hidden and shown again, which is very annoying:

With Compose (how I would like it)
The situation is different if I have a native text field in Android. The soft keyboard is not hidden at all (which is what I am trying to achieve with Flutter):

Efforts

I tried different values for android:windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest.xml without anything improving or even changing.

My code
The program would look like this in Compose:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            parent
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = "", onValueChange = {}
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

And the best I could achieve with Flutter:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const App(),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();
  late final TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          controller: _controller,
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Question
How do I get a textfield in Flutter so that the soft keyboard reappears immediately under Android if the user has switched apps in between and returns to my app?
